# Where does $(a^2+2ab\cos(\theta)+b^2)^{p/2}+(a^2-2ab\cos(\theta)+b^2)^{p/2}$ have a Maximum?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Consider the real-valued function $$
\phi : [0,2 \pi) \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \\
\phi (\theta)=(a^2+2ab\cos(\theta)+b^2)^{p/2}+(a^2-2ab\cos(\theta)+b^2)^{p/2}$$ for $1<p$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.

Where does this function attain its maximum/minimum? Does this depend on the choice of $a,b$ and $p$?

If we compute the derivative we get:

$$ \phi ' (\theta) = -abp \sin(\theta)((a^2+2ab\cos(\theta)+b^2)^{p/2-1}-(a^2-2ab\cos(\theta)+b^2)^{p/2-1})$$

The derivative vanishes at $0, \frac{\pi}{2}, \pi$ and $\frac{3 \pi}{2}$.

So we have to inspect:

$$ \phi(0)=\phi(\pi)=(a^2+2ab+b^2)^{p/2}+(a^2-2ab+b^2)^{p/2} = ((a+b)^2)^{p/2}+((a^2-b^2)^2)^{p/2}$$

and

$$ \phi(\pi /2)=\phi(3\pi /2)=(a^2+b^2)^{p/2}+(a^2+b^2)^{p/2}$$

I can't really see which of the two is the max/min. How can we see which is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put $u=(a+b)^2$, $v=(b-a)^2$ , we have $2(a^2+b^2)=u+v$. Put $f(x)=x^{p/2}$. You want to compare $\displaystyle f(u)+f(v)$ and $\displaystyle 2f(\frac{u+v}{2})$. If $f$ is convex on $I$, you get $\displaystyle f(\frac{u+v}{2})\leq \frac{f(u)+f(v)}{2}$, and the inverse inequality if $f$ is concave. Now compute the second derivative of $f$ to finish.